# show that the strip is mappable to the half plane(conformal map)

Tags: complex-analysis

This is part of another problem.
show that for any real numbers ${a<b}$, the strip ${\{ z \in {\bf C}: a < \mathrm{Re}(z) < b \}}$ is complex diffeomorphic to the disk ${D(0,1)}$

I tried to map the strip to the upper half plane using an exponential and a linear transformation as described in the hint. So I took $z \to \lambda e^{z}$ Then I have x going from $a+i \infty \to a - i\infty$ $f(z)$ goes from $\infty \to 0$. Similary as x goes from $a-i\infty$ to $b-i\infty$ we have f(z) going from $0 \to 0$. Similarly as x goes from $b-i\infty$ to $b+i\infty$ I have $f(z)$ go from $0 \to \infty$.as x goes from $b+i \infty$ to $b - i \infty$ f(z) goes from $\infty \to 0$. I have made a mistake. What could that be?

Comment: saulspatz' answer is probably way more useful to you from a practical point of view, but I'd still like to add that this is a special case of the Riemann mapping theorem: All simply connected domains which are not all of $\mathbb C$ are complex diffeomorphic to each other. Strips and half planes included.

Comment: Thanks @Vercassivelaunos

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

$e^z$ maps the strip $0<\Im(z)<\pi$ to the upper half plane, so start by mapping the given strip to this strip.

Comment: What function would I use @saulspatz?

Comment: It's just rotation, translation and scaling.